# Image and link width in footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a clickable image centered in a footer area. I've tested on Chrome and Firefox and the entire footer is clickable. Chrome inspector shows the  element as 0 pixels tall and 0 pixels wide. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#footerLogo { 
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 73px;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <a href="#"><img id="footerLogo" src="/images/footer.gif"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `#footer` a `text-align: center` to mark centering of elements within it, and `margin: 0 auto` to the `#footerLogo` and remove the `display:block` - since the block sets the `<a>` tag to box and occupies the whole parent container.

http://jsfiddle.net/T4PSS/

Comment: removing display:block fixed the "entire footer is clickable" issue, and "text-align: center" did the trick of centering it, now I don't need to specify widths or margins (I have removed the margin:auto), and I can add text and it still keeps centered, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="footer">
    <a href="#"><img id="footerLogo" src="/images/footer.gif" /></a>
</div>
```

notice how I closed the img element   `/>`

The problem with the whole footer clickable is the `display: block`  , also take out the margins for the img

```
#footerLogo { 
    display:block;  //this line - take it out
    width: 73px;
}
```

if you want to center it , then center `<a>`

```
#footer a {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
width: 74px; //this may be necessary for IE7
}
```

Comment: Tested on Chrome and FF, no difference, sorry

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

without a specified width, apply `id="footerLogo"` to the `<a>` instead:

```
<style>
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #footerLogo {
        display:block;
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <a id="footerLogo" href="#"><img src="/images/footer.gif" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have specified a width (edited the question CSS) and the issue persists

Comment: yeah let me update my answer, you'll need to wrap it in another div cause `<a>` is an inline element

Comment: actually you can just specify the css on the `<a>` instead

Comment: You said "without a specified width", but you specified a width of 200px, why?

Comment: because you are specifying `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` css can't calculate the value when there is no width specified on the element that it's trying to auto position.

Comment: if you don't want to specify the width of the element do what @Anne did with `text-align: center`

Comment: @ruda.almeida - it is fine to only specificy the width of an image - it will render proportionatly with the set width - however don't get in a habit of doing this , it slows down the rendering process